# pass dynamic data to child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a child component as

```
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() messageData: string | string[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

I have a parent component where in template I use the above component

```
<app-alert *ngIf="!!alertsCount" [type]="'danger'"
       [messageData]="alertMessageData"></app-alert>


<mat-select class="select--width--130" (selectionChange)="changeAlertType($event)" [(value)]="alertType" placeholder="Alert Types">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let alertType of alertTypes" [value]="alertType.name">
    {{ alertType.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

in parent component ts

```
getAlertMessageData(alertType: string) {
  switch (alertType) {
    case 'firing':
    case 'silenced':
    case 'resolved':
      this.alertMessageData = `There are ${this.alertsCount} ${alertType} alerts`;
      break;
    case 'all':
      this.alertMessageData = `There are ${this.alertsCount} alerts`;
      break;
  }
  console.log(this.alertMessageData);
}

changeAlertType(event: MatSelectChange) {
  this.alertType = event.value;
  this.getAlertMessageData(event.value);}
```

However the message data does not get updated when I change the selection of alert type, how do I pass messageData so that it is updated after I change mat-select?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't get updated?

Comment: You are passing `[type]="'danger'"` but I dont see `Input() type` in your child component also on `changeAlertType()` method you are calling `getAlertMessageData()` without passing alert type that method expecting param though doesnt it throwing error?

Comment: When change it the messagedata does not get updated in the template of parent and its the same as default.

Comment: @KamranKhatti sorry I missed on that parameter when I was typing the question. the child has a @Input() type.

Comment: @RishavTandon also are you passing `alertType` param in `getAlertMessageData()` method inside `changeAlertType()` method where you are calling the `getAlertMessageData()`  method?

Comment: @KamranKhatti I am calling getAlertMessasgeData(event.value) and passing the type in the changeAlertType() function and it is called when select  is changed

Comment: @RishavTandon you `console.log(this.alertMessageData);` alert message does this change or this also prints the default one? If default then console `alertType` and see if the value of alert type falls any of the case you used ?

Comment: I notice your switch statement doesn't have a default case.  If an unexpected value comes through, `this.alertMessageData` never gets set.

Comment: @KamranKhatti the console.log(this.alertMessageData) changes and updates but the template does not change.

Comment: @RishavTandon can you just print the message in template and see if it changes `<p>{{ alertMessageData }} </p>`

Comment: @BizzyBob I understand but as I said it console.logs the correct message but does not show the correct message in the template and I guess the default is required but not the part of the problem I need to focus on

Comment: @KamranKhatti I need to use in with child component, it works if I do it that way but I need to pass to child component and display it.

Comment: @RishavTandon can you share the html of child component where you are using the message also try to print `<p>{{ alertMessageData }} </p>` in child component and see if it has the value

Comment: @KamranKhatti I will upload stack blitz soon

Comment: @RishavTandon if you have stackblitz it will really help to debug, waiting

Comment: if you're **not** using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` an `@Input` **should be suficient**, see if you has an error in console. For know about changeDetection see [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see from the code is you are passing string or an array of string. When you are passing string, you can detect changes using `ngOnChanges` provided that you are able to send data correctly from the parent component.

When you pass array, you need to changes the reference as array is an object and will be passed by reference and angular changes detection will not detect any changes to it even if you are using `ngOnChanges`.

When you use `ngOnchanges` you can use set property on `@Input` and set the property and run the changeDetection.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() set messageData: any = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    // code here
    // make changes here
  }
}
```

I suggest you to read [this](https://www.oncehub.com/blog/angular-change-detection). How change detection works?

Comment: Thank you for the answer but ngOnChanges I need to avoid because its not good practice. What i am looking for is some answer related with observable.

Comment: Can you share the link which suggests that? It depends on the need if you don't want to use it. You can use rxjs  observables pass the updated values and subsribe them in the view using async pipe. No need to worry about the changes detection, it will be updated auto on the view.

Comment: @Apporva I will share the link, can you suggest how it can be done using rxjs observables and the async pipe?

Comment: Also, you should check [this](https://dev.to/nickraphael/ngonchanges-best-practice-always-use-simplechanges-always-1feg) and if you are worried about performance then you should go for OnPush strategy instead of default one.

Comment: Yes, I can share the link, but you might need to changes the change detection strategy, I have added one link in the answer go through that. The issue you are facing is because of the changes detection and the way you are passing the data to child.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Observable

```
messageSubject = new BehaviorSubject('');
alertMessage$ = this.messageSubject.asObservable();

// In your switch statement
this.messageSubject.next(`There are ${this.alertsCount} ${alertType} alerts`);
```

// Pass the observable in child component as input

```
<app-alert [messageData]="alertMessage$ | async"></app-alert>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.